# Numbers and Letters in an HTML Ordered List with Position "Outside"

Tags: html, css, position, html-lists

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iE3o8.jpg)

Hi Everyone,

Is it at all possible to have a number AND a letter in an ordered list with position "outside" and  without any dots? See image …

Comment: What searching have you done? Could you show what code you have tried so far?

Comment: Dear A Haworth, Thank you for your reply. I looked at dozens of posts as well as articles but was not able to accomplish what I had in mind with the list method. Since I’m not adept at coding I was wondering, if someone in this community had an idea. Meanwhile, I circumvented the ul, ol, li method and decided to add the numbers/letters by hand inside a flex box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can read here, here is a position outside
[CSS Styling list](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp)

```css
ul.a {
  list-style-position: outside;
}

ul.b {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<h1>The list-style-position Property</h1>

<h2>list-style-position: outside (default):</h2>
<ul class="a">
  <li>Coffee - A brewed drink prepared from roasted coffee beans, which are the seeds of berries from the Coffea plant</li>
  <li>Tea - An aromatic beverage commonly prepared by pouring hot or boiling water over cured leaves of the Camellia sinensis, an evergreen shrub (bush) native to Asia</li>
  <li>Coca Cola - A carbonated soft drink produced by The Coca-Cola Company. The drink's name refers to two of its original ingredients, which were kola nuts (a source of caffeine) and coca leaves</li>
</ul>

<h2>list-style-position: inside:</h2>
<ul class="b">
  <li>Coffee - A brewed drink prepared from roasted coffee beans, which are the seeds of berries from the Coffea plant</li>
  <li>Tea - An aromatic beverage commonly prepared by pouring hot or boiling water over cured leaves of the Camellia sinensis, an evergreen shrub (bush) native to Asia</li>
  <li>Coca Cola - A carbonated soft drink produced by The Coca-Cola Company. The drink's name refers to two of its original ingredients, which were kola nuts (a source of caffeine) and coca leaves</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi arsyaadi, thank you for the link. As far as I can tell running the code snippet just produces dots outside the list. I’m looking for a way to have numbers and letters (without dots) positioned outside.